# Проверка масива на совпадения

Tags: php

Есть n-кол-во массивов.
Нужно проверить все эти массивы с одним и найти хотя бы одно совпадения, если есть, то возвращать true, если нету не одного совпадения то возвращаем false. Если есть пустов массив то его просто пропускаем.

> Например масив с которым нужно сравнить

```
0 => '29',
1 => '26',
2 => '8'
```

И есть три масива

> Первый:

```
0 => '3'
1 => '8'
```

> Второй пустой массив, его нужно пропустить и не учитывать.
>
> Третий:

```
0 => '1'
1 => '40'
```

В итоге проверяет с первым массивом и возврашает true, второй пропускает, третий возвращает false.
Потом нужно проверить если есть хотя бы один false то возвращать false, не смотя на то что первый true.

Вот пример, только как закинуть это все в цыкл что бы все это было динамически , кроме того масива с которым сравниваем.
Что бы оно узнавало сколько масивов пришло нам на проверку, потом каждый масив подставлял сравнивать, и вовзращал true или false, и что бы пропускал пустые массивы.

```
$stat = array (29,26,8,9);
//var_dump($cat); 
$cat1 = array (1,2,3,7,8,26);
$cat2= array (1,2,3,7,8);
$cat3= array (1,2);
$cat4= array (9);
$result = array_intersect($cat1, $stat);
if($result === Array()){
 echo 0;
} else{
 echo 1; 
}
```

Comment: Что у Вас есть? Для сравнения массивов можно использовать: `array_diff` и `array_intersect`

Comment: У меня есть массивы которые я привел в примере, только массивов может быть и 10 и 20,  и мне нужно найти хотя бы одно совпадение с тем массимом который я задал статичным. И вот если среди этих всех проверок хотя бы один вернул false то просто выходим с цыкла и отдаем false

Comment: просто true или false

Comment: Нужно в итоге сравнить эти все массивы и если хотя бы в одной случии не будет найдено совпадений то возвращаем false.

Comment: откуда собственно вы берете входные массивы, если вы не знаете сколько их?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Опишите выходные данные. Проверочные массивы лучше сложить в один:

```
$input = [29, 26, 8];
$arr1 = [3,8];
$arr2 = [];
$arr3 = [1,40];

$data = [$arr1, $arr2, $arr3];
```

Далее, фактически вам надо массив `$data` свести к одному значению. Для этих целей можно использовать функцию [`array_reduce()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-reduce.php). дальнейший результат можно вычислять как логическое `И` (`&&`) между предыдущим сравнением, и текущим пересечением. Если же входной пустой, то просто брать предыдущее значение:

```
$result = array_reduce($data, function($result, $arr) use ($input){
                    if(!$arr) return $result;
                    return $result && array_intersect($input, $arr);
                }, true);
```

---

можно изначально отфильтровать пустые входные:

```
$data = array_filter($data);
....
```

и тогда проверка `if(!$arr)` уже не нужна

Comment: так заработал и ваш вариант, спасибо большое)